# Transforming coordinates in R?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, polygon

I have been struggling for a few hours trying to transform SpatialDataFrame coordinates to another type. I have two objects from two different sources, I need to plot them together.

```
> class(Object1)
[1] "RasterLayer"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"

> head(coordinates(Object1))
            x        y
[1,] 13.35000 46.99917
[2,] 13.35083 46.99917
[3,] 13.35167 46.99917
[4,] 13.35250 46.99917
[5,] 13.35333 46.99917

> projection(Object1)
[1] "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"
[6,] 13.35417 46.99917

> class(Object2)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

> coordinates(Object2)
          [,1]     [,2]
7657  454777.5 119375.8
32166 539358.5 129256.9
49121 617992.2 151211.0

> projection(Object2)
[1] "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"
```

If I try to plot them together, only the first Object is displayed.

```
library(tmap)
tm_shape(Object1) +tm_raster() +tm_shape(Object2) + tm_borders()
```

One might hope that this would work, but only in my dreams:

```
> coordinates(Object2) <- coordinates(Object2)/10000
Error in `coordinates<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(45.4777468962329, 53.9358522795272,  : 
  setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have already been set
```

I know that I should use `spTransform()`, but simply I don't know how to correctly reference the transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working with different Coordinate Reference System (CRS), so you cannot  expect to show both layers at the same time without reprojecting one of them. You have a raster layer and a vector layer, in this case, always is recommend to reproject vector layer (reprojecting a raster layer distort the information).

To use `spTransform()`, you need to set the desired output projection:

```
projection(Object1)
[1] "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs"

projection(Object2)
[1] "+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# use crs() to extract CRS from raster
Object2reprojected <- spTransform(Object2,crs(Object1))

library(tmap)
tm_shape(Object1) +tm_raster() +tm_shape(Object2reprojected) + tm_borders()
```

[image]